# Drupal Add 'OR' Condition with hook_views_query_alter()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created my own module to listen for a specific view name and current_display.  I'm attempting to write a function that inserts an OR condition within the following WHERE statement.

```
WHERE (( (field_data_field_size_category.field_size_category_value LIKE '%11 - 20 fl oz%' ESCAPE '\\') 
AND (field_data_field_neck_finish.field_neck_finish_value BETWEEN '21' AND '40') ))
```

The ideal solution would be to insert two more OR statement as follows:

```
 WHERE (( (field_data_field_size_category.field_size_category_value LIKE '%11 - 20 fl oz%' ESCAPE '\\') 
 AND (field_data_field_neck_finish.field_neck_finish_value BETWEEN '21' AND '40' OR
 field_data_field_neck_finish_2.field_neck_finish_value_2 BETWEEN '21' AND '40' OR
 field_data_field_neck_finish_3.field_neck_finish_value_3 BETWEEN '21' AND '40') ))
```

Or with the following groupings:

```
     WHERE (( (field_data_field_size_category.field_size_category_value LIKE '%11 - 20 fl oz%' ESCAPE '\\') 
     AND (field_data_field_neck_finish.field_neck_finish_value BETWEEN '21' AND '40') OR
     (field_data_field_neck_finish_2.field_neck_finish_value_2 BETWEEN '21' AND '40') OR
     (field_data_field_neck_finish_3.field_neck_finish_value_3 BETWEEN '21' AND '40') ))
```

The code that I am attempting to alter the query with is as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function bottle_finder_query_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'product_listing_page' && $view->current_display == 'listing') {

    foreach($query->where[1][conditions] as $key=>$val){
        if($val['field']=="field_data_field_neck_finish.field_neck_finish_value"){
            //dpm($query->where[1][conditions],$name=NULL,$type='status');
            $query->add_where_expression(2,"field_data_field_neck_finish_2.field_neck_finish_value2",array('value'=>array('0'=>$val['value'][0],'1'=>$val['value'][1]),'operator'=>'BETWEEN'));
            dpm($val['field'],$name=NULL,$type='status');
        }
    }
    dpm($query->where[1][conditions],$name=NULL,$type='status');
    drupal_set_message("I can make changes to the view here..");  
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance you may have.

Comment: What is your question again?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in mind?

```
function bottle_finder_query_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
...
$filter = $query->createFilter('OR');
$filter->condition('some field machine name','some value');
$query->filter($filter);
```

This is just very roughly written to give you an idea on how it should work (keeping fingers crossed :-)).